# Under what conditions can we say that $G/N \cong S \implies G \cong N \times S$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, automorphism-group, quotient-group, direct-product

For a recent project (which I have since completed) I needed to derive the automorphism group of the cube graph, and I wanted to do so with some reasonable degree of rigor. I defined a group action of $S_4$ on the four pairs of distance three vertices and noted that the kernel of the induced homomorphism is the identity and the permutation that flips every pair of vertices in the block. This is $C_2$, so by the first isomorphism theorem:
$$\text{Aut}(\text{Cube})/C_2 \cong S_4 $$
I also know that Aut(Cube) $\cong C_2 \times S_4$, so it seems natural to simply "multiply" by the quotiented group in the above equation. However, I know that this is not a legitimate step, because, for instance $C_4/C_2 \cong C_2$ while $C_4 \not \cong C_2 \times C_2$.

So, my **question** is two-fold: **one**, is there a way to derive Aut(Cube) $\cong C_2 \times S_4$ from my argument, and **two**, are there certain nice conditions under which a direct product of a quotient group and the quotient *is* isomorphic to the whole group?
$$N \times G/N \cong G$$

Comment: If you are asking whether, for a group $G$, $G/C_2 \cong S_4 \Rightarrow G \cong C_2 \times S_4$, then the answer is no. $G = {\rm GL}(2,3)$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @DerekHolt I am wondering under what conditions is the implication true, or more specifically how I could proceed and prove that the automorphism group of the cube is $C_2 \times S_4$.

Comment: It is almost never true. You would need all extensions to split (so that's a cohomological question), *and* for all morphisms $S\to\mathrm{Aut}(N)$ to be suitably "equivalent" so that all split extensions are isomorphic to the direct product and you don't have any nontrivial semidirect products. This is rare.

Comment: To prove that the automorphism group of the cube is $C_2 \times S_4$, just note that the $S_4$ is the rotation subgroup, for which the matrices have determinant $1$, whereas the $C_2$ is the reflection defined by $-I_3$, which is central.

Comment: In general $G\simeq N\times S$, iff $G$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $S$ such that $sn=ns$ for all $n\in N, s\in S$. In the case of symmetries of a cube you can use the fact that the map interchanging all pairs of opposite vertices comes from the linear transformation $-I_3$ (place the origin in the center of the cube, and all the isomorphisms become linear transformations). That is, a scalar matrix. Those commute with all the other linear transformations, so you are done. $S=\langle -I_3\rangle$.

Comment: Perhaps it should be mentioned: A nice condition which implies $\text{Aut}(\text{Cube}) \cong C_2 \times S_4$ is existence of an isomorphism $f : \text{Aut}(\text{Cube}) \to  C_2 \times S_4$. To derive $\text{Aut}(\text{Cube}) \cong C_2 \times S_4$, construct an isomorphism $f : \text{Aut}(\text{Cube}) \to  C_2 \times S_4$.